# Calling same action with different urls in cakepphp

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am trying to call an action with two different url's

For example, following are my url's, here username is the parameter and news is the action,
if i enter the first url it works fine and executes the news action, if i enter the second url i am getting error, i need to call the news action if i enter the second url, how can i achieve this by routes.

Thanks..

```
http://domain.com/username/news
http://domain.com/username
```

Below is the route for the first url

```
Route:
Router::connect('/:sluguser/:action', 
array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'news'),
array('pass' => array('sluguser')));
```

Comment: What CakePHP version are you using? It can't possibly be 2.0, 2.1 and 2.3 at the same time. So tag more specifically and don't just spam every possible version.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in 2.3.6